# Dúvidas com modelagem no banco de dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um pequeno projeto e não tenho muita experiência com banco de dados e tendo dificuldades para modelar suas tabelas. O projeto consiste em um gerenciador de saídas, onde teremos produtos normais (como produtos de um mercado) e produtos compostos por outros produtos (como uma cesta básica que possui vários produtos simples dentro). Vou precisar também registrar a data da saída, fornecida pelo usuário e o nome dele. A primeira modelagem que criei ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela geral produtos eu tinha em mente que seria um local onde armazenaria tanto os códigos dos produtos simples quanto dos compostos, mais já percebi que foi desnecessário. Alguém poderia me sugerir como ficaria uma boa modelagem?

Comment: Olá! O que seria a data de saída fornecida pelo usuário neste contexto de produtos? Seria a data de venda do produto?

Comment: Ola @Dherik, isso mesmo, o usuário que forneceria a data de saida